How can I make an error bars plot from a pivot table?
I am working on a dataframe with multivariables; I used the pivot table function to rapidly calculate the mean values for every group and created another table that has the very same index but displays the standard error (sem).
I wanted to create a line plot with the error bars but I am stacked here, I don't have much experience with this kind of tables unfortunately.
df = pd.read_excel('Arabidopsis.xlsx')
df.head()

 Sync  Time (rel/ms) Salinity Accession  Rep Type   No.  PAR  Y (II)   ETR  \
0  LCS        1312510       No        ET    1   FO  9801    0   0.793   0.0   
1  NaN        1332567       No        ET    1    F  9802   35   0.243   3.6   
2  NaN        1352554       No        ET    1    F  9803   63   0.308   8.1   
3  NaN        1372540       No        ET    1    F  9804   91   0.350  13.4   
4  NaN        1392537       No        ET    1    F  9805  126   0.324  17.1   

      qP     qN     qL    NPQ  y(NO)  Y(NPQ)  
0  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000   0.000  
1  0.336  0.377  0.123  0.465  0.517   0.240  
2  0.464  0.566  0.225  0.932  0.358   0.334  
3  0.534  0.588  0.283  1.008  0.324   0.326  
4  0.503  0.616  0.265  1.116  0.319   0.357  

df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='PAR', columns=['Salinity','Accession'], values=['ETR'], aggfunc=['mean'])
df_pivot

    mean                                                        
              ETR                                                        
Salinity       No                             Yes                        
Accession     AOT      ET     PV8     UB6     AOT      ET     PV8     UB6
PAR                                                                      
0           0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
35          4.075   3.950   3.675   3.950   4.500   4.625   3.525   4.675
63          7.625   8.250   7.250   7.300   8.775   9.550   7.250   8.050
91         11.400  13.050  10.850  10.375  12.375  13.225  10.625  11.225
126        15.475  16.850  13.925  12.975  15.075  16.175  13.200  14.025
175        19.825  19.875  16.425  15.100  17.275  18.225  15.100  16.150
266        22.450  21.900  18.000  16.575  18.825  19.475  16.650  17.825
399        23.675  22.800  18.600  17.325  19.900  20.450  17.425  18.950
592        23.650  22.425  18.300  17.250  20.425  20.625  17.350  19.425
875        24.000  22.525  18.300  17.675  20.925  20.900  18.150  20.650
1147       24.100  23.500  19.300  18.225  22.225  21.450  19.100  20.775
1606       24.475  23.125  19.250  17.725  21.800  21.275  18.775  21.475
2096       21.825  19.825  17.175  16.300  21.150  18.950  17.850  19.200

df_pivot_sem = df.pivot_table(index='PAR', columns=['Salinity','Accession'], values=['ETR'], aggfunc=['std'])/16
df_pivot_sem

  ETR                                                     
Salinity         No                                     Yes             
Accession       AOT        ET       PV8       UB6       AOT        ET   
PAR                                                                     
0          0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
35         0.065426  0.023105  0.028584  0.018042  0.036799  0.023593   
63         0.094975  0.036264  0.099281  0.034233  0.062786  0.112904   
91         0.110043  0.074390  0.147063  0.051633  0.087258  0.137251   
126        0.099919  0.125675  0.168586  0.062370  0.122833  0.130242   
175        0.067387  0.180088  0.192731  0.073065  0.159130  0.126282   
266        0.089341  0.235905  0.194253  0.100568  0.193136  0.113694   
399        0.127105  0.253568  0.197445  0.107695  0.206849  0.119733   
592        0.124635  0.250124  0.201363  0.087871  0.223687  0.144191   
875        0.154195  0.228695  0.214026  0.107937  0.239866  0.104333   
1147       0.147990  0.227932  0.236456  0.099788  0.253331  0.110456   
1606       0.125766  0.293256  0.252307  0.093733  0.273719  0.170887   
2096       0.183028  0.228752  0.300450  0.104458  0.134387  0.133902   

                               
                               
Salinity                       
Accession       PV8       UB6  
PAR                            
0          0.000000  0.000000  
35         0.031198  0.015625  
63         0.106372  0.042543  
91         0.133598  0.057367  
126        0.121299  0.081550  
175        0.123533  0.096623  
266        0.122952  0.111146  
399        0.126900  0.129753  
592        0.115976  0.140810  
875        0.088756  0.182039  
1147       0.125312  0.172782  
1606       0.138573  0.240571  
2096       0.165005  0.188539  

